# Parse Tanh in Math.NET Symbolics

Tags: f#, symbolic-math, mathnet-numerics, math.net, mathdotnet-symbolics

Does the MathNet.Symbolics.Infix parser have a way of identifying more complicated trig functions such as tanh? I have tried the following in F# but it is not recognised (I get an undefined expression). When I replace 'tanh' with 'cos' it works just fine.

```
open MathNet.Symbolics

let exp = Infix.parseOrUndefined "tanh(x)" //undefined

printfn "%s" (LaTeX.format exp)
```

Any other libraries for parsing mathematics expressions in F# would also be of interest to me if they can handle functions such as tanh. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.NET Symbolics can work with hyperbolic functions. You got the wrong result, because there was a small error in the library. Now it is fixed. You can wait for the next version or build DLL from source.

Comment: Can confirm that this now works by cloning https://github.com/mathnet/mathnet-symbolics, running build.cmd and creating a reference to /out/lib/NET40/MathNet.Symbolics.dll. Thanks!

Comment: @mwpb,btw, if you have any questions on using the library, you can just do ping me in the [chat F#](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/51909/f)